# Laravel 6 verify email leaving database field null

Tags: laravel-6

I have setup my own custom notification for reaching out to my users to verify their email. They don't get their verification email at registration. They register, I call them and screen them, then approve their registration. After I approve them, they get a verification email. All this is working great. However, when the user clicks their verification link in their email, it takes them to the login page but in the database, the `email_verified_at` column never updates with a time stamp. I've followed multiple tutorials and can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening.

This is my notification function in my controller that I'm using for the screening process:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable);
    }

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
        ->line(Lang::get('Please verify email.'))
        ->action(
            Lang::get('Verify Email Address'),
            $this->verificationUrl($notifiable)
        )
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
}
```

and here is my verification controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
    $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
}
```

When I hover over the link in mailtrap, it has a valid URL and, as stated, redirects to the login screen.
I can supply any other code requested, I just didn't want to paste 5 files worth of code here if it wasn't necessary as all the other functionality seems to be working fine. If anyone can help me figure out why this is happening, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you got this error because your contructor controller block the route, if so then, on `VerificationController` you need to expect the route on `function __construct()` like as : `$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['account/security/resend/email']]);`

Comment: hi @sta, I've updated my question to contain the construct method of the VerificationController. Can you tell me if that looks correct?

Comment: I'd say the problem is the `$this->middleware('auth');` so it never reaches the `verify` method (at least if they're not yet logged in).

Comment: thanks a bunch @Thomas, i'll give that a try. should I remove it or place it at a different location within the function?

Comment: adding `->except('verify')` is probably enough